# How can I pivot this list of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Channels`

```
var blocks = new List<Block>();
foreach (var channel in ChannelsCollection)
{
    var ch = channel.ChannelCollectionItems.Select(item => new Channel
    {
        Id = channel.Id, 
        Delay = item.Delay,
        Trigger = item.Trigger,
        Restore = item.Restore,
    }).ToList();

    blocks.Add(new Block { Id = index++ , Channels = ch});
}
```

This results in a list of `Blocks`, each of which contains a list of `Channels`.

e.g.

```
Block1          Block2          Block3          Block4
    Channel1        Channel1        Channel1        Channel1
        Val1            Val1            Val1            Val1
        Val2            Val2            Val2            Val2
        Val3            Val3            Val3            Val3
    Channel2        Channel2        Channel2        Channel2
        Val1            Val1            Val1            Val1
        Val2            Val2            Val2            Val2
        Val3            Val3            Val3            Val3
    Channel3        Channel3        Channel3        Channel3
        Val1            Val1            Val1            Val1
        Val2            Val2            Val2            Val2
        Val3            Val3            Val3            Val3
```

I need to pivot this list so that I have a list of `Channels` that contain each `Block` for that channel.

e.g.

```
Channel1    
    Block1        Block2        Block3        
        Val1            Val1            Val1  
        Val2            Val2            Val2  
        Val3            Val3            Val3  

Channel2
    Block1        Block2        Block3        
        Val1            Val1            Val1  
        Val2            Val2            Val2  
        Val3            Val3            Val3            

Channel3
    Block1        Block2        Block3        
        Val1            Val1            Val1  
        Val2            Val2            Val2  
        Val3            Val3            Val3
```

Is there a quick way, (e.g. with LINQ) to do this?

**Edit**

`Channel` and `Block` are defined as:

```
public class Channel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Delay { get; set; }
    public string Trigger { get; set; }
    public string Restore { get; set; }
}

public class Block
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your Channel and your Block class?

Comment: Is Channel have a Block Collection property?

Comment: `ChannelCollectionItems`?

Comment: Where could we store the Block in the Channel? Also, what's ChannelCollectionItems? It isn't in your channel definition...

Comment: What is `index++`, i don't see this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the solution:

```
public class ChannelRowCell
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Delay { get; set; }
    public string Trigger { get; set; }
    public string Restore { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ChannelRowCell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public static class DigiChannelsExtensions
{

    public static List<ChannelRow> GetRows(this List<DigiChannelsVM> digiChannelsVms)
    {
        var blocks = (from vm in digiChannelsVms
                      let ch = vm.ChannelCollectionItems.Select(item => new 
                      {
                          vm.Id,
                          Type = item.Types.EnumDataItems.FirstOrDefault(xx => xx.IsSet).Description,
                          Delay = item.Delay.Value.ToString(),
                          Trigger = item.Trigger.Value == 0 ? "+" : "-",
                          Restore = item.Restore.GetSelectedEnumItems().FirstOrDefault().Description == "Restore" ? "Y" : "N",
                      }).ToList()
                      select new { Id = vm.Id.Value, Channels = ch }).ToList();

        var channelRows = new List<ChannelRow>();
        //for (var i = 0; i < blocks[0].Channels.Count; i++)
        for (var i = 0; i < blocks[0].Channels.Count; i++)
        {
            var channelRow = new ChannelRow { Cells = new List<ChannelRowCell>(), Id = i+1 };
            foreach (var cc in blocks.Select(block => block.Channels[i]))
            {
                channelRow.Cells.Add(new ChannelRowCell
                {
                    Delay = cc.Delay,
                    Name = cc.Type,
                    Restore = cc.Restore,
                    Trigger = cc.Trigger,
                });
            }

            channelRows.Add(channelRow);
        }

        return channelRows;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
var channels = blocks
    .SelectMany(b => b.Channels.Select(c => new { b, c }))
    .GroupBy(p => p.c.Id)
    .Select(g => new { Channel = g.First().c, Blocks = g.Select(p => p.b) });
```

As others have pointed out, your `Channel` class doesn't have anywhere to store a sequence of `Block`s, so this returns a sequence of anonymous objects with  a `Channel` called `Channel` and an `IEnumerable<Block>` called `Blocks`.

Note that it also compares `Channel`s by `Id`, since they don't appear to be comparable otherwise. If your `Channel`s are inconsistent between `Block`s, this just takes the `Channel` from the first `Block`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var r = blocks
    .GroupBy(b => b.Channels.Select(c => c))
    .Select(g => new { Channel = g.Key, Blocks = g.Select(b1 => b1) });
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want - it's roughly analagous to `var r = blocks.Select(b => new { Channel = b.Channels.AsEnumerable(), Blocks = Enumerable.Repeat(b, 1) });`